# Error parsing XML unbound prefix using xmlns:sliding

Tags: android, xml, layout, xml-namespaces, sliding

I'm trying to use the [jfeinstein sliding menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu), that imho, looks promising. I like the idea of work with it [using the layout config](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu#usage), rather than code. I've the following very simple layout configuration.

```
<com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu
xmlns:sliding="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/slidingmenulayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
sliding:viewAbove="@layout/customforabove"
sliding:viewBehind="@layout/customforbehind"
sliding:behindOffset="120dip"
sliding:behindScrollScale="0.25"
```

/>

But I got an error saying about unbound prefix. I don´t know if it is because of the sliding after xmlns, or any other reason.

Tks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I thought it should be

```
xmlns:sliding="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/auto"
```

(no dash)

And replace "auto" with the package name where to find that sliding menu library

Try:

```
xmlns:sliding="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.slidingmenu.lib"
```

And this should be in the top element for whatever resource file you use this in (next to the xmlns:android is the right place to be)

Answer (score 0):

The "android" in the names of the attributes 'android:id',  'android:layout_width' and 'android:layout_height' is also a namespace prefix, and thus ordinarily would need an appropriately filled out attribute named 'xmlns:android' somewhere in the markup.

Answer (score 0):

I had this answer just a minute ago.
Fixed it by doing:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```